# Find the last div on the page and call its click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can you do that work?

```
$('.modal-backdrop.active').last(function(){
    $('.button-clear.button').click();
});
```

The idea is to find the last div in the list and click a button that contains class `.button-clear.button`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looked all the answers, so i thought to have this in different way.

```
$('.modal-backdrop.active').children().last().find('.button-clear.button').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `.modal-backdrop.active` selects the container,

try

```
$('.modal-backdrop.active div:last-child .button-clear.button').trigger('click');
```

Comment: That would trigger a click on the last DIV within `.modal-backdrop.active`. Not on the button

Comment: I understood the OP wanted to find the last `.modal-backdrop.active`. So I upvoted Paul Kozlovitch. The the question is not clear enough

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.modal-backdrop.active:last .button-clear.button').click();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.modal-backdrop:last-child').find('.button-clear.button').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying you're selector to pass in a context. You set the context to be the last div that you're looking for, and then find the button within it.

```
$('.button-clear.button', $('.modal-backdrop.active').last()).click();
```